# How can I run vgg16 (transfer learning) on my GPU which has 4GB of memory?

Tags: pytorch

I want to use `VGG16` (transfer learning), but I don't have enough memory:

- According to `nvidia-smi` I have 4GB of memory
- Model:

  ```
    model = torchvision.models.vgg16(pretrained=True)          
    for p in model.parameters():
        p.requires_grad = False

    sin                 = model.classifier[0].in_features    
    model.classifier = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(sin, 128), nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Linear(128, 2)
    )
  ```

According to: `torchinfo.summary(model, (64, 3, 224, 224))`

```
Estimated Total Size (MB): 7046.64
```

And I'm trying to train it with:

```
DEVICE    = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu") 
model     = model.to(DEVICE)
adam      = optim.AdamW  (model.parameters(), lr=1e-4, betas=(0.9, 0.99), weight_decay=2e-4)
loss      = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

model.train(True) 
for ii, (x, y) in enumerate(trainDL):
    x = x.to(DEVICE)
    y = y.to(DEVICE)
    
    z   = model(x) 
    ...
```

Where `trainDL`  is `torch.utils.data.DataLoader`

- versions:

  torch==1.10.0

  torchinfo==1.5.3

  torchvision==0.11.1

I'm getting `CUDA out of memory` (which seems true because I have less GPU memory than the model size)

1. How can I use `vgg16` (transfer learning) and run it on my GPU ?
2. What do I need to change in my code above to make it runs on my GPU ?

Comment: Have you tried reducing the batch size? 64 batch size is using 7 GB. Probably 32 or 16 should work.

Comment: small batch size may reduce model preformance (batch normalization...) so I want to try and use 64 batch size.

Comment: you can try mixed precision training

Comment: Does it have to be VGG16? Maybe there's a pretrained model with a smaller memory footprint? Maybe EfficientNet?